# Find missed elements in array of numbers

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have array with numbers 1...31 (days at month)
On my side I would like to find all missed numbers.
This my solution but I not sure that is a good way.

```
var result = new List<int>();
int[] days = GetSelectedDays(); //I recive array with 1..31 with some missing elements sometimes (without "5" as example it depends if user has selected this number)
for (int i=0; i <30; i++)
{
  if (!days.Contains(i))
  result.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question? [ask]

Comment: Are you receiving this array from somewhere else?

Comment: I woud like to find better soultion then i have

Comment: OK. What are you comparing to that would identify that the number is missing? At the moment, that solution looks OK.

Comment: Sorry. Just seen GetSelectedDays call. Does this return a List<int> also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ `Except`:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Except(days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are currently checking numbers in the range 0..29 as opposed to 1..31.  The only suggestion I have is to change the for loop to:

for (int i=1; i <= 31; i++)

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you're adding days of a month its probably easier to loop through a loop of DateTimes, i.e.

```
var missedDateDictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>(); // or other value
var date = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01);

for (int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
{
    var newDate = date.AddDays(i);

    //do something with adding / not adding date

    if (notDoneSomething)
        missedDateDictionary.Add(newDate, true)
}
```

The premise here is that each DateTime you're adding is unique.

If you cant guarantee that, your solution is pretty efficient but could use some optimization.

1. Initialize arary with max value: `int[31] days = GetSelectedDays();`
2. A month can have 31 days: `for (int i = 1; i <32; i++)`
3. If at all possible, fill `result` in the loop you're filling `GetSelecteDays()`